# Como incrementar número a partir dum click no botão

Tags: python

Quero um botão que adicione ''+1'' ao label que e exibido na Janela do `tkinter`, mas não sei muito bem como fazer, e não achei nada no Google, o que eu entendi não retorna o que eu queria, em vez de ir somando ex: aperta o botão "+" 1x ele muda o valor pra 1, aperta novamente ele muda o valor pra 2, novamente pra 3(somando +1 cada vez que clicado), e ao contrario com "-" diminuindo esse mesmo numero 3,2,1 caso necessário

```
from tkinter import*
janela = Tk()
text = 0


def bt7_click(): #botao +
    soma =(text)
    lb4["text"] = str(text + 1)

def bt8_click():
    soma =(text)
    lb4["text"] = str(text - 1)



lb4 = Label(janela,text="0",font="Arial 50", fg= "red", bg="white")
lb4.place(x=50, y=50)


bt7 = Button(janela, width=1, text="+", command=bt7_click)
bt7.place(x=130, y=90)
bt8 = Button(janela, width=1, text="-", command=bt8_click)
bt8.place(x=150, y=90)


janela.geometry("200x200")
janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia,

para você conseguir fazer este controle de incremento e decremento você vai precisar de um acumulador

você pode utilizar o próprio campo como acumulador por exemplo,

com algumas pequenas modificações no seu código, você consegue fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
from tkinter import*
janela = Tk()

limite = 0

def bt7_click(): #botao +
    val = int(lb4["text"])
    lb4["text"] = str(val + 1)

def bt8_click():
    val = int(lb4["text"])
    if val <= limite:
        val = limite + 1
    lb4["text"] = str(val - 1)


lb4 = Label(janela,text="0",font="Arial 50", fg= "red", bg="white")
lb4.place(x=50, y=50)
bt7 = Button(janela, width=1, text="+", command=bt7_click)
bt7.place(x=130, y=90)
bt8 = Button(janela, width=1, text="-", command=bt8_click)
bt8.place(x=150, y=90)

janela.geometry("200x200")
janela.mainloop()

lb4["text"] = '0'
```

Comment: Bom dia, muito obrigado, eu tinha tentado algo parecido porem desta forma ” val = int(text)”” que não era correta, tem como por um limite para que não fique negativo? -1, -2? Apenas, vá até 0?

Comment: Bom dia, opa, tem sim vou editar a resposta, mais na prática vc so vai precisar criar uma variável definindo o limite `limite = 0` por exemplo, ai dentro do click de decremento você faz a validação

Comment: resposta editada